# Size of various datatypes on Windows 64 bit platform - specifically sizeof(int)

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 as my IDE environment. Obviously, my machine is running Windows 7 x64, and I am trying to develop a 64 bit program.

Note, however, that the compiler is Nvidia's nvcc (I've verified that I downloaded the 64 bit version).

For the sake of detail, this is the compile command that Visual Studio prints out:

```
 D:..."C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvcc.exe" -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile   -g   -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "...kernel.cu" -clean
```

It appears that it is compiling in 64 bit as it should.

If that is the case, this is what I have noticed:

```
When compiled to run on a Windows platform...

(1) sizeof(int) == 4
(2) sizeof(long) == 4 //Where 1 and 2 are true regardless of platform, x86 or x64
(3) sizeof(long long) == 8
```

Is this accurate? And if it is, does this mean that I have to declare a long long in order to work with an 8 byte "like" integer in Windows? (Meaning that I need to avoid doubles and floats).

Comment: When compiled *using Visual C++* to run in Windows.  The size of the various types depends more on the compiler than on the OS.

Comment: @cHao Really? Show me a Windows-compatible compiler which doesn't have 16-bit shorts, 32-bit int/longs, and 64-bit long longs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I saw that article. However, I wanted to verify that my compiler settings were correct.

Comment: @Sneftel: Haven't seen one...but haven't looked either, and it doesn't matter either way.  The Windows API (regardless of bitness) hardly ever uses fundamental types directly, precisely because it's a bad idea to make assumptions about the sizes of stuff -- particularly stuff that the compiler is expressly allowed to define as it sees fit (within the limits specified in the standard).

Comment: From an API architecture perspective, it certainly makes sense to abstract. From a programming perspective, though, you can safely assume those type widths as long as you're not doing embedded or weird mainframe programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, integers in MSVC are 4 bytes.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) for details on MSVC sizes.

For 8 byte numbers, use `long long` or `double`.

Comment: Good to know...wasn't sure if I missed switching my compiler mode to 64 bit somewhere or not.

Comment: or use types from `<stdint.h>`

Answer (score 3):

`long long` is guaranteed by standards to be 64 bit or longer, so your guess is correct. However, for clarity, it is best to include `<cstdint>` and use `int64_t` or `int_least64_t`.